# Obtener el codigo_usuario de una base de datos, usando sesiones

Tags: php, mysql

Actualmente, estoy trabajando con sesiones en una pagina web, la cual emula a la red social "LinkedIn", para que un usuario pueda realizar una publicacion, se ejecuta la siguiente peticion MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_publicaciones(codigo_usuario, contenido_publicacion, numero_likes, fecha-publicacion, ubicacion) 
        VALUES (%s,'%s',null,NOW(),'%s')"
```

para poder publicar la informacion en la tabla tbl_publicaciones, se necesita el codigo del usuario, el cual no se como implementar en la consulta ya que el codigo del usuario lo tengo implementado en la pagina "muro.php" donde se realizan las publicaciones

```
$sql = sprintf( 
    "SELECT codigo_usuario, codigo_genero, nombre_usuario, apellido_usuario, correo, contrasena, url_imagen_perfil, titular, educacion, logros FROM tbl_usuarios WHERE correo = '%s' and contrasena = '%s'",
    $_SESSION["usr"],
    $_SESSION["psw"]);
```

Este es el codigo php que tengo en la pagina "muro.php"

Comment: La información es bastante pobre, vamos a necesitar un poco más de contexto para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Como dice Anion, dejas bastante poca información. Aun así, dices que trabajas con sesiones, de modo que tendrás algo parecido a $_SESSION['codigo_usuario'] en algún momento en tu muro.php no?
Si no lo tienes, debes crearla para luego, cuando lo necesites en tu consulta, poder traerte ese dato de sesión generado previamente

Comment: Que es el codigo_usuario? es una session o un codigo "ID" registrado en la base de datos para poder ayudarte tendrás que esforzar a presentar más información.

Comment: Es un codigo ID del usuario registrado